# C# Updating a MySQL table when editing a datagrid doesn't work

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, datagrid

I'm making a small simple program that shows a mysql table in a datagridview and that saves the data back in the table after editing it in the datagridview itself when pressing a button.

The "filling" of the datagrid view with the mysql table works perfectly.
But I'm getting an error at the "update line" when pressing the save button.
error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

The code used to fill in the datagridview:

```
 private void roster_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        db_connection();
        mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from members", connect);
        DS = new DataSet();
        mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];

    }
```

and the code when pressing the save button:0

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            db_connection();
            mySqlDataAdapter.Update(DS.Tables[0]);
        }
```

Can anyone help me figure out why it's failing ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you encounter an exception too generic you can use a `Try/Catch` block and analize the `InnerException` of your `Exception`. For example (VB.NET):

```
Try
    db_connection()
    mySqlDataAdapter.Update(DS.Tables(0))
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message(), MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    If Not IsNothing(ex.InnerException) Then MsgBox(ex.InnerException.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
End Try
```

In this case, probably you only have to set `.InsertCommand`, `.DeleteCommand` and `.UpdateCommand` of `MySqlDataAdapter`.

Please note that you don't always need to set these 3 commands; i.e. if a user can't delete rows in your table then you don't need to set a `.DeleteCommand`.